# Why autoplot function don't show the 95% confidence interval, but plot function do?

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

The autoplot function don't display the 95% confidence interval in graph. It show only 80% ic.

[image]

Plot function displays both ic, 80% and 95%.

[image]
What I'm doing wrong in the autoplot?

I already tried to change the autoplot arguments, but nothing seen to change the output graph.

The data I'm using is a ts (time series) like this:

Time-Series [1:71] from 2012 to 2018: 3.0515 -2.0783 -1.2 -3.2055 -0.0132 ...
[image]

The model output looks like this:
[image]

```
forecasts <- HoltWinters(temp, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE, l.start=3.0515) 
forecasts_12 <- forecast(forecasts, h=12) #projeção 12 meses a frente
plot(forecasts_12)
autoplot(forecasts_12)
autoplot(forecasts_12, PI = TRUE,shaded = FALSE, pi.col="#FF3B6F", fcol = "#0000AA", flwd = 0.5, se = FALSE)
```

I would like to display the confidence interval of 80% and 95% with autoplot function.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this, `forecast:::autoplot.forecast` is showing both 80% and 95% confidence bars for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have loaded the ggfortify package which has its own autoplot function, and that is masking the autoplot function from the forecast package. I strongly recommend you don't use ggfortify. It doesn't play nicely with other packages.